# MySql update statement with subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

please take a look at this statement i'm writing in MySql Workbench:

```
update customer set flag = 1
where id in (select id from customer
group by phoneNumber
having count(phoneNumber) > 1);
```

The following message is shown:

```
Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'customer' for update in FROM clause
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please post some sample data and desired resultset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try that:

```
  update customer set flag = 1
  where id in (select * from (select id from customer
  group by phoneNumber
  having count(phoneNumber) > 1)t ) ;
```

Comment: It works! Please explain me why the additional 'select *' is needed?

Comment: because in additional select doesnt have FROM table . in your error saids cant specify target table , so you need a subquery.

Comment: Oh I get it now... i'm beginning with MySql, and people tell MySql are full of these little 'gotchas'... now I'm starting to understand :) thanks for the help, I will mark as answered as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

Here is another variant trying to avoid the gotcha (I used another group by stmt, see below. It might not reflect what it is you are trying to do):

```
update customer a
join ( select id
   from customer b
   group by id
   having count(1) > 1 
) b on a.id = b.id
    set a.flag = 1;
```

Part of your statement `select id from customer group by phoneNumber` is btw another quirk of mysql. In sql92 it is invalid, and unless id is functionally dependent of phonenumber it is also invalid in sql99 and later. You can enforce a stricter behaviour by setting ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY in @@sql_mode.